# Will there be any vulnerability in a simple LOG IN using IF ELSE statment in PHP

Tags: php, security, login-script

Will there be any vulnerability if I use a simple **LOG IN** using **IF ELSE** statment. I have tried various injections but didnot succeded in any of them, because there is no database/SQL in it. I am using this only for protecting a single page.

```
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
if  ($username=='admin' AND $password=='password')
{
    echo "<b>Welcome, Admin!</b> You have logged in!";
}
else 
{
    echo "Sorry! Incorrect Login.";
}
```

Comment: unless you share your password or this file, it won't be vulnerable! Long strings take long time for Brute-force attack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is surely not susceptible to injection attacks as there is nothing to inject any way (like you pointed out).

Things to improve:

- Storing passwords in plaintext is generally a really bad idea. Use hash-Values instead.
- Password and Username should be sent over encrypted connection (https)
- If you are using apache web server use .htaccess file for password protection instead. You'll find many examples on the web